How do I combine my 3 stored procedures or can I leave it as it is?
I have one update stored procedure and 2 insert stored procedures in SQL Server as shown here.
UPDATE:
UPDATE DW.dbo.table2 
SET Active_ind = 0,
    expiry_date = GETDATE(), 
    updated_date = GETDATE()
WHERE hash_key IN (SELECT T1.hash_key
                   FROM table1 T1 
                   LEFT JOIN DW.dbo.table2 T2 ON T1.hash_key = T2.hash_key
                   WHERE T1.hash_dif <> T2.hash_dif
                     AND T1.Active_ind = 1) 
  AND Active_ind = 1

INSERT 1:
INSERT INTO DW.dbo.table2 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE hash_key IN (SELECT T1.hash_key
                       FROM table1 T1 
                       LEFT JOIN DW.dbo.table2 T2 ON T1.hash_key = T2.hash_key
                       WHERE T1.hash_dif <> T2.hash_dif
                         AND T1.Active_ind = 1)

INSERT 2:
INSERT INTO DW.dbo.table2 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE hash_key NOT IN (SELECT T2.hash_key
                           FROM DW.dbo.table2 T2
                           WHERE T2.Active_ind = 1)

I basically want to run the UPDATE stored procedure every time. For the INSERT I want to combine them so it does the INSERT on the same hash_key with a different hash_dif OR do the insert into table2 if the hash_key from table1 doesn't exist.
Can I combine these 3 stored procedures cohesively? When I run all 3 at the same time, they run fine so can I just leave it like that?

Why not have one procedure that does all, known as an upsert, rather than 3 procedures?

Look at MERGE. (Don't forget HOLDLOCK!)

You might want to change what you are asking, because the answer to "can I leave it as it is" is yes if it works. What is the motivation behind the question?

To state what might be obvious to many (but perhaps not all) is that a stored procedure can have more than one statement. Just include all three statements in sequence within the body of a single stored procedure. If needed, you can add a parameter to the stored procedure along with IF ... ELSE ... (perhaps combined with BEGIN ... END) to control execution.

Is hash_key a unique key? If so why are you using a self-join, why not insert/update directly from table1? If not what are the relationships? It's really not clear what exact result is desired.

@dale K i cant accept any answers because theyre left as comments. if you leave as an answer in my post ill choose it as best

i accepted them now as i was going through them. for the others i cant accept an answer and i suggested posting it as a proper response
